# regular expression generation

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to check a string should contain only letters and space.No other character other than letter [A-Z] and space are allowed.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete regex looks like this

```
^[A-Z ]+$
```

You can simply create a character class and put the characters in that you want to allow:

```
[A-Z ]
```

if you want to allow also lower case letters then use

```
[A-Za-z ]
```

or use the i (IgnoreCase) option

So your character class matches 1 character. you want to repeat it to match more than one character.

`+` would be at least one character, where

`*` would additionally match 0 characters

As last step you need to ensure that the complete string is matched, you can do this using anchors.

`^` matches the beginning of the string

`$` matches the end of the string (or a newline if you use the m (multiline) option

Answer (score 2):

A character class should be sufficient

```
[A-Z ]+
```

i.e. one or more of letters between A-Z and space

Comment: true, ^[A-Z ] whould have been a better answer! thnx

Answer (score 0):

Check that the string matches the following:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex character classes can be negated by putting a `^` symbol at the begining of them.

Your example could be negated like this: `[^A-Z]`. Add a space to allow the full range of characters you want to check for and you have `[^A-Z ]`.

Now you have a validator that meets your criteria: If that regex returns true then your validation fails.

Since you didn't specify the programming language you're working in, I can't help you much further than that.

Answer (score 0):

This will match what you need:

```
^[A-Z\s]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

try matching with this regex

```
^[A-Za-z\s]+$
```

this should do the trick